# Entity Framework SubmitChanges

Tags: entity-framework

I have trigger on table A to change the column value on table B during new row insertion on table A.

Due to current design I am getting RowVersion error. So I am thinking to perform current trigger functionality on entity `SubmitChanges`. I believe that `INotifyPropertyChanged` fired on property change, in my case will be fired on table A property change, which is I not what I want. I want to perform operation on table A row insertion to update value on table B.

Anyone have idea what is better way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `SaveChanges`, get all entities to be inserted to table A and perform your updates on entities from table B.

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) 
{
    foreach(TableA a in ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                                          .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                                          .Select(e => e.Entity)
                                          .OfType<TableA>())
    {
        // Here you can get your TableB entity and do an update
        // If you don't have those entities already loaded you will load
        // them one by one so it will probably need some additional 
        // adjustments for better performance
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(options);
}
```